# How to copy files to local machine from remote machine

Tags: putty

My local machine is windows OS and remote machine is Linux based.
Have tried many tools to do the task but my main problem is the multilayer of authentication used.

I have to using putty first login to server 1 (first step of authentication) and then from server 1 login to the remote machine where required files are residing.

Please suggest

Comment: Use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net) and it's [connection tunneling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/tunneling).

Comment: Try pscp.exe from the PuTTY folks.

Comment: Thank you Honza and Paul for your quick assistance.

Comment: Tunneling through WinSCP solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Download pscp from here: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

Navigate to the folder where you downloaded pscp.exe.

Run command to download the file:

```
pscp -r user@192.168.1.10:/var/lib/file.txt C:\APPS
```

The answer is taken for [here](https://superuser.com/a/385445/889834)